# Is constrained least squares regression convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

Would anyone know if the following optimisation can be a 'convex' optimisation with a global minimum under certain conditions if any?

minimise w.r.t x, || Ax - b ||^2

such that

f(x) <=0

g(x) = 0

?

For example would the above be convex with a global minimum if A was a positive definite matrix?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please learn mathjax soon

Comment: This is a convex program if $f$ is convex and $g$ is linear. Also, the target function to minimize is always convex regardless of $A$, and since a norm is bounded below be zero, it always has a global minimum

Answer (score 1):

That would depends on the property of $f$ and $g$. If $f$ is convex and $g$ are affine, then the domain is convex.

$\|Ax-b\|^2$ is always convex regardless of whether $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks, I was experiencing a situation where even the unconstrained version was giving me different answers with different starting values (so local minima?) using Excel's solvers GRG Optimiser. 

If its convex, a solver should get the same solution with any starting point right?

I'm beginning to doubt Excel solvers method and my formulation :)

Comment: I haven't used Excel's solver before. If a problem is convex, all local min are global solution. Does it stop after a few iterations and return the best solution found?

Comment: It says "The solver has converged to the current solution. All constraints are satisfied"

Which is the same message it gives when I have a global solution

Comment: It's possible a location optimum, may we know the $f$ and $g$? Are they convex and affine?

Comment: For your problem, all local optimal are global optimal thought the solution need not be unique.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the feedback so far.  I've posted a simplified version of the problem which gives me local minima that are not the global minima here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794569/can-the-least-squares-objective-have-local-minima-which-is-not-the-global-minima Hopefully this will help isolate my problem.