# Can the least-squares objective have local minima that are not global minima?

Tags: convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

The unconstrained least-squares problem

$$ \min_x \| A x - b \|_2^2 $$

should be  a convex objective with a global minimum having the pseudo inverse analytical solution

$$ x_{\min} = \left(A^T A \right)^{-1} A^T b $$

based on section 1.2.1 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook). What confuses me is that the example below which has the above form, gives me local minima (which is not a the global minima) using the Excel solver.

$$ \min_x \| A x - b \|_2^2 $$

where

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 & 0 \\ 0 & p_2 & p_2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ 
b_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

where all $p_i, b_i > 0$. I thought this was quite strange since the least-squares objective seems convex regardless of what $A$ is? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh0h0mv9v6ueje4/test-3d-LS-mix-variables-small.xlsx?dl=0)'s the problem setup using the Excel solver. Not really sure what I might be missing. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: hi, can you elaborate on what are your $p_1, p_2, b_1, b_2, b_3$ in your excel file? In which cell did you compute the least squae problem?

Comment: Sure, I've indicated the p_i and b_i in the excel file in the 'Test Cases' sheet. The 'optimisation' sheet has the variable and objective referring to that data. There is no b_3 btw, just b_1 and b_2. I've fixed the typo in the post.

Comment: You might have to download the Excel file to see both the sheets. I could only see the first sheet in the dropbox web preview

Comment: Section 1.2.1? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a careless mistake.

From your excel working, the intended matrix should be

$$\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_{\color{red}1} & 0 \\ 0 & p_2 & p_2\end{bmatrix}$$

rather than

$$\begin{bmatrix} p_1 & p_2 & 0 \\ 0 & p_2 & p_2\end{bmatrix}$$

The rank of $A$ is $2$ and hence it must be consistent. A possible solution is to set $x_2=0$, then $x_1 = \frac{b_1}{p_1}$ and $x_2=\frac{b_2}{p_2}$.

Comment: Hi Goh,
Actually the element (2,2) in matrix $A$ is intentionally $p_2$. Note that the cell D4=Optimization!$C$4 where as D3==Optimization!$C$5. 
This the reason. 

I can understand your reasoning of setting one variable to zero in a $Ax-b=0$ but I'm not sure how this would work with minimising $||Ax-b||^2_2$ as the variables in $x$ can change to make the objective lower?

Comment: =[@Percentage2]*[@[Total Delivery Phase Budget]] is the formula use in G3, so everyting in the first equation is always multiplied with $7.19$ isn't it? If the system $=$  is consistent, then we can attain $\|Ax−b\|^2=0$ which is optimal since it is nonnegative.